# Faulty vector constructor in MSVC? (Vector of raw arrays)

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2019, c++20

The following (contrived example) does not compile in MSVC with `/std:c++latest` (tested in VS 2019 16.10.3):

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int[2]> v(2);
}
```

failing with C2440: 'return': cannot convert from `int *` to `_Ty (*)` (with `_Ty=int [2]`, in a placement new statement, for context).

Is this a known bug? Is there a drop-in workaround without falling back to an old standard? (`vector::resize` doesn't work either.)

Comment: `std::array<int, 2>` as the element type would work.

Comment: `std::vector` cannot operate with array types like `int[2]`. Wrap `int[2]` with a struct/class to make it work. Or use `std::array` instead of `int[]`

Comment: I've done some reading, and it looks like this actually is not supposed to work. [(1)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) *"Generally, it is required that element type meets the requirements of Erasable"*, [(2)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Erasable) *"[erasable] is equivalent to the validity of `p->~T()`"* [(3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.dtor#:expression,pseudo-destructor_call) *"[in] a pseudo-destructor [call], `T` shall be a scalar type"*. Since arrays are not scalar types, `int[2]` is not erasable, so vectors can't hold it.